# Focal ratio importance for planetary viewing

Tags: jupiter, saturn

It seems that almost every article online regarding planetary viewing recommends a telescope with a high focal ratio (f/8 or more), for revealing the finer details of the planets. But I find this a bit confusing because the resolving power of a telescope is solely a function of the aperture, or at least that is my understanding.

Given the above, shouldn't it be a matter of a large enough aperture and then the eyepiece to use to zoom on the detail of choice in formed image?

Comment: The f/number controls the total light collection **per solid angle**  - if you don't get enough photons, you won't be able to see details due to insufficient contrast.

Comment: But isn't aperture what decides how many photons you "collect"?

Comment: but also how many photons get to your eyeball depends on f/# because of the effective magnification implicit in the value

Comment: Here is where it gets confusing for me. Isn't higher focal ratios associated with "slower" image taking? Why is that the case if higher focal ratios equate with more photons?